# Failed to connect to repository : Error performing git command: ls-remote -h https://github.com/hichemmehdi/EmployeeManager.git HEAD

Tags: git, docker, jenkins

I can not access the repo from jenkins from a multipipeline job.

I am using this command to have jenkins:

```
sudo docker run -p 8181:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /home/ubuntu/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk11
```

My credentials are correct, I already use them with `git bash`.

I am on ubuntu 20.

Comment: This message means something failed.  Unfortunately, you haven't provided us enough information to tell us what.  Are there additional error messages or more logging that you can include?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using https instead of using ssh.

Thank you guys.